# Python to MS SQL Error: Error when connecting to SQL using sqlalchemy.create_engine() using pypyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pypyodbc

Scenario:

1. I am trying to Convert the SQL output directly to Table using dataframe.to_sql, so for that i am using sqlalchemy.create_engine() and its throwing error when trying to createngine()

   ```
    sqlchemyparams= urllib.parse.quote_plus(ConnectionString)
    sqlchemy_conn_str = 'mssql+pypyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(sqlchemyparams)
    engine_azure = sqlalchemy.create_engine(sqlchemy_conn_str,echo=True,fast_executemany = 
    True, poolclass=NullPool)
    df_top_features.to_sql('Topdata', engine_azure,schema='dbo', index = False, if_exists = 
    'replace')
   ```

2.It will work fine if i use:pyodbc

```
sqlchemy_conn_str = 'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(sqlchemyparams)
```

3. So is there any way i can using pypyodbc in sqlchem_conn_str

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: Thank u Jon and Gord for the response... Please find the error its throwing NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mssql.pypyodbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy does not have a `pypyodbc` driver defined for the `mssql` dialect, so

```
mssql+pypyodbc:// …
```

simply will not work. There may be some way to "fool" your code into using pypyodbc when you specify `mssql+pyodbc://`, similar to doing

```py
import pypyodbc as pyodbc
```

in plain Python, but it is not recommended.

In cases where pyodbc cannot be used, the recommended alternative would be `mssql+pymssql://`.

Comment: 1.i am trying to run py file using Azure Machine learning pipeline notebook. There i am unable to install pyodbc, So i went for pypyodbc, So is there a way to do to_sql without sqlalchemy, instead of using normal pyodbc connection iterating over each item and inserting?

Comment: If you are unable to install pyodbc then how do you set up pypyodbc?

Comment: import os
os.system(f"pip install pandas")
os.system(f"pip install scikit-learn")
os.system(f"pip install pyodbc") .............it gives below error:"message": "{'code': ExecutionFailed, 'message': [{\"exit_code\":1,\"error_message\":\"Execution failed with error: Traceback (most recent call last):\\n  File \\\"xyz.py\\\", line 14, in <module>\\n    import pyodbc as pyodbc\\nModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyodbc'\\n\\n\",\"process_name\":\"/azureml-envs/azureml..................but when i replace it with os.system(f"pip install pypyodbc")  and import pypyodbc as pyodbc it works fine.

Comment: adding to this error: src/pyodbc.h:56:10: fatal error: sql.h: No such file or directory
     #include <sql.h>
              ^~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.

Comment: Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyodbc (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Comment: Thank you Gord thompson. It got resolved by using os.system(f"apt install unixodbc-dev --yes") before os.system(f"pip install pyodbc") ....from you answer in : https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/441.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
```

Then create varaibles to holder the server, database, username and password and pass it to...

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                                 "SERVER="+server+";"
                                 "DATABASE="+database+";"
                                 "UID="+username+";"
                                 "PWD="+password+";")

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(params))
```

then upload data to sql using.

```
dfc.to_sql('jobber',con=engine,index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Using https://www.dataquest.io/blog/sql-insert-tutorial/ as a source.

Comment: 1.i am trying to run py file using Azure Machine learning pipeline notebook. There i am unable to install pyodbc, So i went for pypyodbc, So is there a way to do to_sql without sqlalchemy, instead of iterating over each item and inserting?