# Accessing MS SQL from SQLAlchemy by OLE DB

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

currently I am accessing my MS SQL database from Python using SQLalchemy with the Native SQL Client. According to this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/relational-databases/native-client/sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver16) it is deprecated you should use the *Microsoft OLE DB Driver for SQL Server* instead.
My problem now is that I cannot figure out how to change the connection string.
My old working string for the Native client was:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{databaseAccess}@{Hostname:Port}/{database}?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0', echo=True)
```

For the new string my best guess is the following but of course it does not work. I assume the *driver* variable must be different and maybe the *pyodbc* must also be replaced.

```
sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{databaseAccess}@{Hostname:Port}/{database}?driver=Microsoft+OLE+DB+Driver+19+for+SQL+Server', echo=True)
```

Just to make this post complete: The error I get is the following sadly it is in German but it basically says: that the data source could not be found as the driver is no default driver. I strongly assume that this just means my string is wrong.

```
(pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Der Datenquellenname wurde nicht gefunden, und es wurde kein Standardtreiber angegeben (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Comment: Here's how I write my connection string - might be of use? https://stackoverflow.com/a/72546285/2432555

Comment: Be aware that, as with [ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228) and [JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/jdbc-driver-10-2-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3100754), the OLE DB Driver 19 for SQL Server has [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/release-notes-for-oledb-driver-for-sql-server) to do with encrypted connections, i.e. `Encrypt=True/Yes;` is the new default setting.

Comment: Even OLE DB is problematic, at best. YMMV, but accessing SQL Server from SQLalchemy applications is perhaps best achieved using ODBC Driver for SQL Server - at least it's supported on macOS and Linux in addition to Windows.

Comment: To clarify: SQLAlchemy does not support OLE DB connections to SQL Server. ODBC connections are supported via `mssql+pyodbc://` and Microsoft's ODBC drivers (e.g. ODBC Driver 17/18 for SQL Server).